# How to use the style data bindings?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm having difficulties getting the style binding working in KnockoutJS.

```html
<script id="avatarTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div id="avatar_${id}" class="avatar" data-bind="style: 
    { background: s, width: '50px', height: '85px', left: (x + 'px'), top: 
    (y + 'px') }">${s}, ${x}, ${y}</div> 
</script> 

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'avatarTemplate', foreach: avatars }"></div>
```

The result of rendering this template is:

```html
<div id="avatar_1" class="avatar" style="width: 50px; height: 85px;">avatar.png, 0, 0</div>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why all styles which are dependent on the view model do not show up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are observables, then you need to specify it like this:

```
<div id="avatar_${id}" class="avatar" data-bind="style: 
    { background: s, width: '50px', height: '85px', left: (x() + 'px'), top: 
    (y() + 'px') }">${s}, ${x}, ${y}</div>
```

If you use an observable in an expression, then it needs to be specified with (), as it won't get unwrapped automatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6GtV3/

Comment: Ahh, I was wondering how to do KnockoutJS concatenation.. thank you  :o)

Comment: My god! Just spent 30 mins trying to figure out this! =D

Comment: Awesome. I was accessing x() and y() properly, but it didn't occur to me that I needed to add the units 'px'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer but I googled onto this page while investigating.  I had something like this:

```
<div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: src }">
```

where `src` is a value in my model object like "http://image.com/foo.jpg".  Specifying src as a function as in the above answer did not help:

```
<div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: src() }">
```

I found that if the `src` value is not a valid background-image property, it is completely ignored.

I had to use:

```
<div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + src() + '\'' }">
```

Might save someone some pain at some point :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! This was the exact use case I was looking for!