# Knockout style binding: firefox doesn't set background-color?

Tags: css, firefox, knockout.js

When I try to change the background color of a little box using the `style` knockout.js binding:

```
<input class="biggerBox" type="text" data-bind="value: colorText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<div class="littleBox" data-bind="style: {'background-color': colorText}"></div>
```

and in the js:

```
var viewModel = {
    colorText: ko.observable('rgba( 80, 120, 160, 1)')
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

it works just as I expect in Chrome and Safari, the background color of the little box changing as I type text in the input box. But not in Firefox 24.0 on a Mac; the colorText observable changes, but the background color is never set. However, if I try to change the foreground color instead, that works on all of Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I have not tried IE.

Am I misunderstanding the programming here? Or is this a knockout.js bug? Or a Firefox bug? It doesn't seem to be anything to do with [How to use the style data bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363405/knockoutjs-style-bindings-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/emrys57/Z69vE/9/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use `backgroundColor` attribute instead of `background-color`.

Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z69vE/10/).

This is not a Knockout-specific thing. As can be seen in [the relevant KO source code file](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/style.js#L6), the binding sets style like this:

> `element.style[styleName] = styleValue || "";`

Firefox handles this `element.style[...]` syntax different from Chrome, as can be seen if you type the following in both console windows:

```
document.body.style['background-color'] = 'red'
```

This works in Chrome, not in Firefox. (Interestingly, it also works in IE11.)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the alternative attribute naming convention. You win by one minute. And thanks to Tomalak too.

Comment: Interesting! I've done some further investigation and took the liberty of adding my findings to @sinanakyazici's answer.

Comment: @Jeroen Very nice finding. I thought I saw a `dashed-name` to `propertyName` conversion function somewhere in the KO source so I assumed they would to do "the right thing". Obviously they don't.

Answer (score 9):

Using the alternative syntax to define CSS class names works in Firefox:

```
<div class="littleBox" data-bind="style: {backgroundColor: colorText}"></div>
```

To find out the reason a look at the source code would be necessary.